# Avoiding to print out a certain word in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm just starting to learn python. I am doing this exercise which asks the following:

"Implement a program that requests a list of words from the user and then prints each word in the list that is not 'secret'."

This is what I have so far but it seems that it is not working when the code is executed. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
wordinput = input('Enter a list of words: ')

def keep_secret(l: wordinput) -> list:
    for i in wordinput:
        if i == 'secret':
            return None
        else:
            print (i)
```

Comment: You can simplify your logic and just make sure it prints only `if i != 'secret'`:.

Comment: other than the `return` bug: do you actually *call* `keep_secret`?  And do you call it with `keep_secret(wordinput)` or `keep_secret(wordinput.split())`?

Comment: I am calling it with "keep_secret(wordinput)" within a print statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do this

```
wordinput = input('Enter a list of words: ').split()

def keep_secret(l: wordinput) -> list:
    for i in wordinput:
        if i == 'secret':
            continue 
        else:
            print (i)
```

You can simplify to this

```
def keep_secret(l: wordinput) -> list:
    for i in wordinput:
        if i != 'secret':
            print (i)
```

Or return the filtered list like this

```
def keep_secret(l: wordinput) -> list:
    return [i for i in wordinput if i != 'secret']

print(keep_secret(wordinput))
```

Comment: Hello gnibbler, thanks for responding. I tried your method suggestion and there seems to be a problem. I am getting this back.

"[
'
s
e
c
r
e
t
'
,
 
'
p
i
c
k
e
l
s
'
,
 
'
m
u
s
t
a
r
d
'
,
 
'
j
e
l
l
o
'
,
 
'
s
e
c
r
e
t
'
]
None"

Comment: And it is printing it character per character. Not sure why.

Comment: @user2891736, ah you need to add a `.split()` to get a list of words from the input

Comment: Where would that come after?

Comment: @EricCuevas, see the end of the first line

Comment: @EricCuevas, don't enter the list as a Python literal list, just the words with spaces between them.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering, but I'm getting really close now, 
it works!
However, it returns a "None" at the end, why does this happen?

Comment: @EricCuevas, functions _must_ return _something_. If nothing is specified, it will default to `None`. You can return the list as I did in the last example

Comment: Yes I see now, thank you for all your help, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this problem as well. Thanks to John La Rooy's solution, here is my take in a shorter version:

```
wordinput = input('Enter a list of words: ').split(', ')

for i in wordinput:
        if i != 'secret':
            print (i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your return statement, you don't wanna return anything otherwise it will terminate the program by returning None